# C++ Use macros to define class member of a single class

Tags: c++, macros

I'm trying to implement a general settings struct to access all the settings of my application in one place. Each module of the app has its own settings class / struct. I want to define a member with type of each module setting in the general settings struct. To make things easier I want to define a REGISTER macro that creates a new member for each module setting.

Something like this:

```
struct Settings
{    
    // I know this is not working
    #define REGISTER_SETTINGS(settings) \
            settings _##settings = ##settings();
};

struct ServerSettings
{
    int port = 8080;
    string ip = "0.0.0.0";
};

REGISTER_SETTINGS(ServerSettings);

struct WindowSettings
{
    int width = 640;
    int height = 480;
    string title = "window";
};

REGISTER_SETTINGS(WindowSettings);
```

In the end my settings struct should look like this:

```
struct Settings
{   
    ServerSettings _ServerSettings = ServerSettings(); 
    WindowSettings _WindowSettings = WindowSettings();
};
```

I have no clue how I should get the macro expansion in there.

Comment: The one-word guide for using macros in C++: **don't**.

Comment: You need to remove the semicolon from the macro, for one

Comment: why do you define the macro inside a struct??

Comment: You can't add members to a struct from outside the struct definition.

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid macros. It wouldn't even have sense`REGISTER_SETTINGS(settings)` in my eyes because you're the programmer, just write those two lines into the Settings struct and you're fine...
But if you still want such a function write it by using a inline function.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, it is better to avoid macros entirely.

However, to respond to the question as asked ....

To declare a `struct` type that has members that are instances of other `struct` types, the compiler must have already seen the declaration of those contained  types.  So simply change the order of the definitions.

```
struct ServerSettings
{
    int port = 8080;
    string ip = "0.0.0.0";
};

struct WindowSettings
{
    int width = 640;
    int height = 480;
    string title = "window";
};

struct Settings
{    
#define REGISTER_SETTINGS(settings) \
        settings _##settings = ##settings()

     REGISTER_SETTINGS(ServerSettings);
     REGISTER_SETTINGS(WindowSettings);

      // etc

#undef REGISTER_SETTINGS
};
```

Note the `#undef` prevents the macro being used outside the definition of `struct Settings`.

There is one key problem though.  This creates identifiers that start with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter.   Such identifiers are reserved by the C++ standard, and using them causes your code to have undefined behaviour.   One way to avoid this is to change the macro to

```
#define REGISTER_SETTINGS(settings) \
    settings a_##settings = ##settings()
```

which prevents creating reserved identifiers.

Second, a declaration

```
 Type name = Type();
```

basically default-initialises `name`, so is functionally equivalent to

```
 Type name;
```

So you can further simplify the macro to

```
#define REGISTER_SETTINGS(settings) \
    settings a_##settings
```

As I said right at the beginning, though, it is better to avoid macros entirely.   Macros simply obscure the fact of doing this;

```
// definitions of ServerSettings and WindowSettings here

struct Settings
{    
     ServerSettings a_ServerSettings;     
     WindowSettings a_WindowSettings;
};
```

which is much easier to read that the obfuscation of macros you are trying to use.   Obviously, you can use whatever naming convention for the members of `Settings` you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
#define REGISTER_SETTINGS(settings)  \
        settings _##settings = settings();
```

note no '##' before `settings()`.

But:

1. As already pointed out in comments: better do *not* use macros.
2. This would not result in what you expect, e.g.:

   ```
   struct Settings
   {   
        ServerSettings _ServerSettings = ServerSettings(); 
        WindowSettings _WindowSettings = WindowSettings();
   };
   ```

   but it would create objects in the place where macro was called:

   ```
   struct Settings
   ...
   struct ServerSettings
   ...
   ServerSettings _ServerSettings = ServerSettings();

   struct WindowSettings
   ...
   WindowSettings _WindowSettings = WindowSettings();
   ```
3. I would suggest using some [creational pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/creational_patterns) like (Abstract) Factory or Factory Method.